# How to get the id of all paragraph which are selected?

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

I am working with android webview and for achieving some functionality i need to integrate javascript. I am new to javascript to please tell me how to get the paragraphs id(id of each paragraph which are under selection). In more details:

Like i am having data-

```
   <p id="01">hhh dhghdg  
    <span id="1.1">dada</span>
    <span id="1.2">dgsdd</span>
</p>
    <p id="02">dsdgs dhgd hdhd
 <span id="2.1">dada</span>
    <span id="2.2">dgsdd</span>
</p>
```

So you select some data i.e "hhh dhghdg dsdgs" so this data belongs to multiple paragraph p1 and p2 so i want to get the id of both the paragraph using javascript.

Please tell me how to get this.

Comment: is your question about how to call these elements using javascript? or you want to find to which ids do the selected text belongs. Can you be a bit clear?

Comment: want to find to which ids do the selected text belongs that means all ids

Comment: You can have a look here http://jsfiddle.net/KC48j/11/

Comment: @Renku yes this is what i need but can you please white this thing in one javascript function

Comment: Why you need it in Javascript just call <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"> in your page use this code

Comment: Daniel - please see my answer below which describes how to get all the elements under selection.

Comment: @Vishnu Renku but how to check whether for each element whether it is having child or not if having than add all those to collection and again check whether elements child is having child ,please add that code also @ jsfiddle.net/KC48j/11

Comment: hello Ravi...were you able to get an answer for it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PPK has a very detailed post:
http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/range_intro.html

Which describes range objects. I've not done this before but by the looks of things you'll need to use:

```
window.getSelection()
```

Which should return a selection object from which you can get a range object which will contain all the selected elements (as described in the link above)

From scanning the docs on MDN:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.getSelection

You'll get an HTML string back from which you could attempt to get all the ids from, using a regular expression, something like this:

```
var underSelection = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
var idsRegEx = /#\s(id|class)="[^"]+"/;
var idMatches = idsRegEx.match(underSelection);
//then clean and do something with the ids
```

I haven't tested any of this but I'm hoping it gets you started.

EDIT: additional info 
If you're using jQuery you might be able to load the selection into a jQuery object and get all the ids out by doing :

```
var IDs = [];
$(underSelection).find("p").each(function(){ IDs.push(this.id); });
```

Comment: idsRegEx.match(selection); what is selection here??

Answer (score 0):

You have to use either

```
document.documentElement.id
```

or

```
document.getElementsByTagName('HTML')[0].id
```